# How can I programmatically tell if the mouse buttons on Ubuntu Linux have been swapped for left-handed users?

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, accessibility, mouse

I need a program that can tell if the mouse buttons have been swapped (i.e. the primary mouse button is the right button mouse instead of the left.) This setting is in Ubuntu's Settings > Mouse > General > Primary Button. How can a program find this setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/left-handed` command at the command-line, which will output `true\n` or `false\n` to stdout.

Here's an example in Python:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['dconf', 'read', '/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/left-handed'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_bytes, stderr_bytes = proc.communicate()

stdout_text = stdout_bytes.decode('utf-8')

if stdout_text == 'true\n':
    print('The mouse buttons have been swapped.')
elif stdout_text == 'false\n':
    print('The mouse buttons have not been swapped.')
```